# Filtering a list by user input

Tags: angularjs

I'm learning AngularJS and I want to filter a list by user input. I have problems understanding how I should approach on this task. I first thought a custom filter, but it didn't make sense to me, since the data has to change live based on the user input and I did not see a solution to solve this by an directive.

A service also didn't make sense to me, since the filter shouldn't be a singleton, since I wanna use it on another place on the website.

This is my code at the moment:

```
angular.module('Demo', [])
angular.module('Demo')
  .controller('FilterController', ['$rootScope', function($rootScope) {

    $rootScope.filter = {
      Tournament: {
        format: "1on1",
        type: "standard",
        mode: "regular",
        groupstage: 0
      }
    };

  }])
  .controller('ListController', ['$scope', '$rootScope', 'filterFilter', function($scope, $rootScope, filterFilter) {

    $scope.tournaments = [
      {
        Tournament: {
          id: 91173389,
          title: "Here goes a cool title",
          format: "5on5",
          type: "standard",
          mode: "regular",
          groupstage: 0,
          buyin: 50.00
        }
      },
      {
        Tournament: {
          id: 91179145,
          title: "What a cool tournament",
          format: "5on5",
          type: "freeroll",
          mode: "knockout",
          groupstage: 1,
          buyin: 0.00
        } 
      },
      {
        Tournament: {
          id: 91180055,
          title: "5K GTD Tournament",
          format: "1on1",
          type: "standard",
          mode: "direct",
          groupstage: 1,
          buyin: 100.00
        }
      }
    ];

    $scope.tournaments = filterFilter($scope.tournaments, $rootScope.filter);

  }]);
```

See the plunk here: http://plnkr.co/edit/vOSifa?p=preview

This code obviously does not work, since the filterFilter-Call in the controller applies just once the controller is loaded.

I'm not really asking for a coded solution, since I'm more interested in how I have to think to solve this problem. I hope you can help me!

Answer (score 0):

The following is a simple solution I found allowing you to filter based on keywords and sort on a single field.

JavaScript: Sorting and filtering data with AngularJS

- Original location: https://gist.github.com/simonbingham/3858121
- Codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rwjBl

JavaScript:

```
function ContactListCtrl($scope){
  $scope.contacts = [
    { "pfirstname":"Simon", "plastname":"Bingham", "ptelephone":"12345" }, 
    { "pfirstname":"Andy", "plastname":"Beer", "ptelephone":"67890" },
    { "pfirstname":"John", "plastname":"Whish", "ptelephone":"13579" }
  ];
};
```

HTML:

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>AngularJS Sorting &amp; Filtering Example</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.1/angular.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app ng-controller="ContactListCtrl">
    <h1>AngularJS Sorting &amp; Filtering Example</h1>

    <form>
      Search: <input ng-model="query">
      <select ng-model="sortorder">
        <option value="">-- sort order --</option>
        <option value="plastname">Ascending</option>
        <option value="-plastname">Descending</option>
      </select>
    </form>

    <p>There are <strong>{{(contacts|filter:query).length}}</strong> contacts<span ng-show="query.length"> matching &quot;{{query}}&quot;</span>.</p>

    <table class="contacts" ng-show="(contacts|filter:query).length">
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Telephone</th>
      </tr>

      <tr ng-repeat="contact in contacts|filter:query|orderBy:sortorder">
        <td ng-class-even="'even'">{{contact.plastname}}, {{contact.pfirstname}}</td>
        <td ng-class-even="'even'">{{contact.ptelephone}}</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This example doesn't really help, since the filter and the list in my application are two seperate modules/controllers/widgets/whatever-you-wanna-call-them.

But still thanks for the answer.